# Can TabView be modified to show images for navigation instead of vector art or text?

Tags: gui-construction

I have see code for TabView in the doc's that provide something close to what I need:

```
TabView[Tooltip[
 Show[CountryData[#, "Shape"], ImageSize -> {30, 30}], #] -> 
DateListPlot[CountryData[#, {{"GDP"}, {1970, 2005}}], 
 ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ CountryData["GroupOf10"]]
```

Which provides the outlines of countries in each tab for navigation.  What I need is a way to use images for each tab navigation.  How can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is nothing you have to really do, just get some images (you can of course just as well `Import` your own ones):

```
img1 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}];
img2 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Truck"}];
```

and use them where you'd otherwise use strings or whatever:

```
TabView[{
  img1 -> "tree",
  img2 -> "truck"
}]
```

it looks somewhat better if the images have the same size:

```
TabView[{
  ImageResize[img1, {100, 100}] -> "tree",
  ImageResize[img2, {100, 100}] -> "truck"
}]
```

The trick here is that "everything is an expression" in Mathematica, and `TabView` accepts any kind of expression for the tab-labels or content, and so do many other similar functions. Unlike in my example you could even literally copy & paste the images into your code and it would work, but I don't think that is usually a good idea...

Comment: Wow, very simple! Thanks Albert Retey !

Answer (score 2):

```
fig1 = Graphics3D[Sphere[], ImageSize -> 30];
fig2 = Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ImageSize -> 30];
TabView[{fig1 -> "My first tab", fig2 -> "My second tab"}]
```